# UWP - Secondary tile sizes

Tags: windows-10, live-tile, uwp

I'm working on a new W10 UWP app, and ran into a small issue.

I'm generating tiles with a separate Tile service - it creates secondary tiles, and updates them when required (and also updates the primary tile).

However, for some reason, even though the Wide and Medium templates are used, the sizes the tile offers when right-clicked are just "Small", and "Medium".

I found no reference on how to enable Wide and Large tile options. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so the solution is simple...

It's not enough to add the Live Tile templates, you have to manually specify the sizes by adding the proper graphics Uris to the SecondaryTile instance. So if you want a wide tile to be available, assign a value to

```
tile.VisualElements.Wide310x150Logo
```

and so on, before calling

```
await tile.RequestCreateAsync()
```

Comment: Oh... So you figured it out by yourself. :)

Comment: Yep, I believe we sent our answers in simultaneously :)